# How can we apply the formula?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I want to calculate $\Delta \ln{||x||}$ for $x=(x_1, x_2)$.

$$\langle \Delta \ln{||x||}, \phi \rangle= \langle \ln{||x||}, \Delta{\phi}\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln{||x||} \Delta{\phi(x)} dx= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon< ||x||<R} \ln{||x||} \Delta{\phi(x)} dx$$

How could we apply the formula $\int_V (f \Delta{\phi}-\phi \Delta f) dV=\int_{\partial{V}} \left( f \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{n}}-\phi \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{n}} \right)dS$ in order to find the value of $\Delta{\ln{||x||}}$ ?

Comment: The second equation is not true. Since $\Delta\log|x|=0$ away from the origin, the limit on the right is $0$. The integral in the middle should be $2\pi\phi(0)$.

Comment: At which point to you mean? @robjohn

Comment: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln{||x||} \Delta{\phi(x)} dx= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon< ||x||<R} \ln{||x||} \Delta{\phi(x)} dx$$

Comment: I was told that it holds for $R$ big enough.

Comment: So is it wrong? If so, why? @robjohn

Comment: Never mind. It is okay.

Comment: Ok... And how can we continue from that point? How can we apply the formula? @robjohn

Comment: Computing $\Delta\phi$ may be difficult and integrating against $\log|x|$ even more so.  It depends on the $\phi$ chosen, but following that approach, it should be applied to all $\phi$.

Comment: @robjohn So do we continue as follows? $$$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon< ||x||< R} \ln{||x||} \Delta{\phi(x)} dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \int_{\epsilon< ||x||<R} \phi(x) \Delta{\ln{||x||}} dx+ \int_{||x||=R} \left( \ln{||x||} \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{\eta}}-\frac{\phi}{||x||}  \right)\right] dS$$

Comment: That's a start, after the bracketing is fixed.

Comment: @robjohn And how can we continue?

Comment: first of all the first integral in the brackets is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking partials
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)}\\
&=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}
$$
symmetry gives
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)
=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
Therefore, away from $(0,0)$
$$
\Delta\log|x|=0
$$
Thus, $\Delta\log|x|$ is a multiple of the Dirac delta. To figure out the coefficient, we compute
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta\log|x|\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\nabla\log|x|\,\cdot n\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{x}{r^2}\cdot\frac xr\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\frac1r\,2\pi r\\[9pt]
&=2\pi
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\Delta\log|x|=2\pi\delta(x)}
$$

Comment: Doesn't it hold that $$\int_{\partial{B}(0,r)} \frac{x}{r^2} \cdot \frac{x}{r} d{\sigma}=\int_{\partial{B}(0,r)} \frac{1}{r^2} d{\sigma}=\frac{1}{r^2} 4 \pi r^2$$ Or am I wrong?

Comment: $x\cdot x=r^2$. The length of a circle is $2\pi r$

Comment: A ok... And then we have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon< ||x||<R} \phi(x) \Delta{\ln{||x||}} dx=4 \pi \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon< ||x||<R} \phi(x) \delta(x) dx=4 \pi \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \phi(\epsilon) $. $$$$
Or am I wrong?

Comment: where do you get the $4\pi$?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $2\pi$.